# Save the output of <bean:message key... bundle /> in a Java String var

Tags: struts, javabeans

I use the code `<bean:message key="zzzzz" bundle="yyyyy" />` to show a message which comes from a file_lang.properties file. The message is shown in english or spanish depending on the language selected.

I need to store this text in a string value cause i need to concatenate with other strings to write it in other part, not a jsp, a text file. How can I do that ???

I try to pass the message into the URL of an hyperlink that i use, but i can't or i don't know how to put the bean:message in the `<a href="...` part.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping it in a JSTL `set` and use the declared `var` afterwards?

```
<c:set var="yourVariable" scope="page"><bean:message key="zzzzz" bundle="yyyyy" /></c:set>
...
<c:out value="${yourVariable}" /> or ${yourVariable} directly (depending on your JSP version)
```

You can also use it directly in your href (it's not nice but it does the job) like:

```
<a href="<bean:message key="zzzzz" bundle="yyyyy" />" ...
```

and you can also retreive it [from the Action class's message resources](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/api/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html#getResources%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) even, if you need that kind of control.

Comment: I will try the first option. The second option didn't work. I use Struts1, and try to add the bean message with other params. Something like this: <a href="page.html&value=1&mess=<bean:message key="zzzzz" bundle="yyyyy" />" ...

Comment: @Jorge Vega Sánchez: What do you mean the second option didn't work, you get an error, it's some unexpected result? From all the options, that one should be the easiest to use and sure to work. You mentioned a text file in your question, how does that relate to what you are trying to do?